# ManifestPlaceholders for multiple elements with same variable

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have the following line:

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="${supportedTexture}" />
```

I inject the correct supported texture in gradle file based on the selected flavor, for example like this:

```
productFlavors {
    ETC1 {
        manifestPlaceholders = [supportedTexture: "GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture"]   
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work if I want to add several `supports-gl-texture` lines in the manifest. So how should I edit `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` file if I'd like to have multiple supportedTextures like this:

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture" />
```

Would it be possible to do something like this in gradle file:

```
productFlavors {
    ETC1 {
        manifestPlaceholders = [supportedTexture: "GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture"]   
    }
    ETC1andATC {
        //manifestPlaceHolders = ???
    }
}
```

Or is my only option to go outside gradle and have for example multiple Manifest files which I copy to project depending on gradle flavor?

Comment: I don't think manifest merger offers a loop construct. There are fairly few cases where that would be useful, yours being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited numbers of supported textures then you can define multiple keys for all those textures and use in the manifest file.

```
productFlavors {
    ETC1 {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
        supportedTexture1: "GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture",
        supportedTexture2: "GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture"]   
    }
}
```

Then in your manifest

```
<supports-gl-texture android:name="${supportedTexture1}" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="${supportedTexture2}" />
```

Comment: The question is really about having variable number of keys in gradle flavors.

So your solution doesn't really help in a case where number of keys varies. I'd like to have one flavor with one texture only (for example `ETC1`) and a second flavor with two textures (for example `ATC` and `DXT`). 

In that case if I have `supportedTexture2` variable, the first flavor will produce an error because it doesn't exist. Then again without the second variable the other flavor cannot have two different textures.

Comment: @Scam then why don't you use the multiple manifest for each flavors?

Comment: I know I can use multiple manifest files (I actually state that in my question). I was just curious if there was any way to use only one manifest. In this case there apparently is not.